# Is there a way to artificially manipulate a dataset in order to replace it for one that gives good results?

Tags: class-imbalance

I'm trying to artificially create a dataset for pure educative reasons but I want it to be based in one particular dataset, the problem is that this original dataset don't make good predictions even with the most powerful methods (with the predictive variables you can't guess the target because they don't have a strong relationship)

My approach to  this problem will be using an oversampling for imbalanced data method, as it usually creates artificially new observations intepoling data from the predictible variables.